# Javascript Loop not working with local storage

Tags: javascript, loops

I have code that loads the variables and turns them into numbers, I can do math with these, and can display them on page, but i have functions, that worked before the loading was added, that use these variables to automatically add 1 to the variables. I have a loop that runs this automatic addition. however the loop does not seem to be working after the addition of the loading.

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {

            var hotdogs = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('hotdogs'), 10);
            var bread = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('bread'), 10);
            var hotdog = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('hotdog'), 10);
            var sauce = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('sauce'), 10);
            var bakeries = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('bakeries'), 10);
            var butchers = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('butchers'), 10);
            var sauceries = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('sauceries'), 10);
        }
        else {
            var hotdogs = 0;
            var bread = 0;
            var hotdog = 0;
            var sauce = 0;
            var bakeries = 0;
            var butchers = 0;
            var sauceries = 0;
        }

function buyBakery(){
            var bakeryCost = Math.floor(20 * Math.pow(1.05,bakeries));     
            if(hotdogs >= bakeryCost){                                   
                bakeries = bakeries + 1;                                   
                hotdogs = hotdogs - bakeryCost;                          
                document.getElementById('bakeries').innerHTML = bakeries;  
                document.getElementById('hotdogs').innerHTML = hotdogs;  
            };
            var nextCostBakery = Math.floor(20 * Math.pow(1.05,bakeries));      
            document.getElementById('bakerycost').innerHTML = nextCostBakery;  
        }; 

(function loop(timer) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                breadClick(bakeries);
                hotdogClick(butchers);
                sauceClick(sauceries);
                customers(custom);
                loop(1000);
            }, timer)
        })(1000)
```

Comment: why not use setInterval instead of the weird thing with arguments and setTimeout?

Comment: what is your browser version?

Answer (score 0):

<del>For starters you don't appear to be calling the `buyBakery()` method within your loop.</del>

Secondly, even though 'Storage' is defined the item you are looking for may not be on it.in that case it'll return `null` instead and `parseInt()` will convert into `NaN`(Not a Number)

also make sure the other functions you are calling within the loop are exist and not throwing any errors.use the web console for that.

you might wanna consider saving values back on `localStorage` (if you are not already doing that) so you can get it later. I've added function to do that on my example.

Try some thing like this.

```
function loadFromLS(item) {
    var ret = 0;
    if (typeof (Storage) === 'undefined') {
        return ret;
    }
    if (null === (ret = localStorage.getItem(item))) {
        ret = 0;
    }
    return parseInt(ret, 10);
}

function saveToLS(item, val) {
    if (typeof (Storage) === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }
    localStorage[item] = val;
}

var hotdogs = loadFromLS('hotdogs');
var bread = loadFromLS('bread');
var hotdog = loadFromLS('hotdog');
var sauce = loadFromLS('sauce');
var bakeries = loadFromLS('bakeries');
var butchers = loadFromLS('butchers');
var sauceries = loadFromLS('sauceries');

function buyBakery() {
    var bakeryCost = Math.floor(20 * Math.pow(1.05, bakeries));
    if (hotdogs <= bakeryCost) {
        bakeries = bakeries + 1;
        hotdogs = hotdogs - bakeryCost;
        document.getElementById('bakeries') .innerHTML = bakeries;
        document.getElementById('hotdogs').innerHTML = hotdogs;  
    };
    var nextCostBakery = Math.floor(20 * Math.pow(1.05, bakeries));
    document.getElementById('bakerycost') .innerHTML = nextCostBakery;
};

(function loop(timer) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        breadClick(bakeries);
        hotdogClick(butchers);
        sauceClick(sauceries);
        customers(custom);
        loop(1000);
    }, timer)
}) (1000)
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't include the all functions and buyBakey is activated by a button also there is a button that saves allt the variables but that is not included

Comment: @user2717118 okay, but have you tried my rest of the code ? if yes, are you still having problems ? have you checked the web browser's console logs ?